# Source of the name Achira - What did עינן have against his brother?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names

The nasi of Shevet Naftali's name was Achira (אחירע), which translates to "my brother is evil." What did Enan (his father) have against his brother, that he should give his son such a name?

Comment: Maybe it translates to ַאֲחִי רֵע my brother-friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are four meanings of the name [Achira](http://www.tanakhprofiles.org/showentries.php?code=01081005%20052110121410&id=138&next=1) given in our tradition.

- The Rishonim say that the "evil brother" is the tribe of Dan, who were guilty of the [Idol of Michah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micah%27s_Idol).
- The Midrash explains that אחירע is derived from באחו and רעוא, and means "Fertile Land."
- The Ohr haChaim plays off the above two, and explains that the name means "my brother[s' land] is bad," from the fact that the tribe of Naphtali viewed their brothers' inheritance as less fertile and bad in comparison to their own allotment.
- Da'at Mikra says that it means "God is my shepherd" (see Psalms 23:1).

[Other explanations](http://biblehub.com/concordance/a/ahira.htm) of the name (by Christian scholars) are "brother of evil , i.e. unlucky" (אחי [מזל] רע), "brother of the shepherd" (אח רעי), and "my brother is [my] friend" ( ַאֲחִי רֵע).

---

**מדרש אגדה (בובר) במדבר פרשת במדבר פרק א**

> ‏[טו] לנפתלי אחירע בן עיין /עינן/ . שהיתה ארצו שמנה לתבואה, כמו שנאמר ותרעינה באחו (בראשית מא ב), ואומר בין אחים יפריא (הושע יג טו), רע הוא לשון רצון, כדמתרגמינן רצון רעוא, זה היה שבט נפתלי, שהיתה ארצו מוציאה פירות כרצון בעליה, וכן משה רבינו ע"ה [אמר] נפתלי שבע רצון (דברים לג כג):‏

**הדר זקנים על התורה במדבר פרשת נשא פרק ז**

> ‏מקשים העולם למה נקראו נשיא דן אחיעזר בן עמישדי ונשיא נפתלי אחירע בן עינן. ומתרצים לפי ששבטו של דן יש בהם פסלו של מיכה ופלטם הענן ובקש דן לנפתלי אחיו שיבקש עליו רחמים שלא יהיה הענן פולטו ואמר לו שיהיה לו אחיעזר בן עמישדי פי' שיהיה לו אח לעזרה שיהיה בן עם אל שדי. ונפתלי השיבו אחירע בן עינן בתמי' כלו' אחי רע שיש בו ע"ז יהיה בתוך הענן:‏

**ר' חיים פלטיאל במדבר פרשת במדבר פרק א**

> ‏וכי יש לך אדם שקורא לבנו אחירע, אלא אל יאמר אדם שכתוב בתורה דבר שלא לצורך כי על שם המעשה נקרא כך כי נשיא דן היה קורא אותו אחי עזר בן עמי שדי ע"ש שבט דן שהיה חוץ לענן וקורא לנפתלי אחיו אחי היה לי לעזר להיות בן עמי שהם במחנה שדי ונשיא נפתלי היה קורא אותו אחירע ועונה לו אחי רע הוא כי פסל מיכה עמו ורוצה לישב בענן.‏

*<sub>Texts taken from Bar Ilan Responsa.</sub>*

**אור החיים, במדבר פרק ז**

> ‏אחירע בן עינן. ירמוז על דרך מאמרם ז''ל (ספרי שם) בפסוק: 
>   שבע רצון, מלמד שהיה נפתלי שמח בחלקו בימים בדגים בפרגיות ומלא ברכת ה' ים גינוסר עד כאן.‏ 
>   והוא מאמר אחי רע פירוש שחלק אחיו היה בעיניו רע בערך חלקו, והיתה עינו מלאה מחלק שנפל בגורלו.‏

*<sub>Text from [Daat](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=4&perek=7&mefar)</sub>*

**Da'at Mikra**

> (אחירע = אחי (או אלי) הוא רעי (*ה' רעי לא אחסר - תהילים כג:א*

Comment: Targum pseudo Jonathan also mentions the idol of Micha when Amalek attacks. He killed Danites, who were unaccomodated by the clouds of glory.

Comment: I believe that's what ר' חיים פלטיאל is referring to.