# Why couldn't Dan defeat the Amorites?

Tags: shoftim--book-of

Chapter 1 of the book of Shoftim (Judges) describes how the Amorites chased the tribe of Dan to the mountains.

My question is why couldn't Dan defeat the Amorites - especially when G-d promised to deliver all their enemies into Israel's hand?

Comment: I think it might have what to do with Pesel Micha but I have to double check

Comment: Pesel Micha is in chapter 18. Not sure they are connected. I searched for an answer but didn’t find one. Curious if you do

Comment: @mbloch Some say Pesel Micha existed before they entered the Land. See: "[Why Was the Idol of Micha Tolerated](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38215/1368)"?